# Why does BigCommerce CMS uses iframe?

Tags: html, css, bigcommerce

Recently I have started working on BigCommerce CMS and studying on how it works. I got to know that the CMS uses iframes to change content dynamically. The CMS page remains the same but it content changes on every action and the content is always displayed in the iframe.

If someone wants to apply the same work procedure for a custom CMS then how he/she can do it?

Comment: WIth "a custom CMS" you mean a CMS that doesn't have iframes? Then it depends on what it does use. AJAX? Or does it reload the whole page?

Comment: No. It doesn't reloads the page. The header, sidebar-navigation and footer remains the same. The main content which contains the functionalities like store management etc gets changed. Those functionalities are being called in an iframe. Whenever someone chooses a different option from the sidebar-navigation then just the main content changes. The entire page doesn't reload. So if someone wants to add the same content changing functionality with the help of an iframe in a custom made CMS, so how can he/she do that?

Comment: All you need to do is change the `src` attribute of the iframe, then it will load the contents itself. Is that what you mean? If not, please explain what the problem is.

Comment: Yes. I want to change the src but, how can I change it dynamically? And is it wise to use iframes in a CMS?

Comment: To change it dynamically, you just write `(id of iframe).src = (url of content)` in JavaScript. But I'm afraid by now your question is becoming a matter of opinion. "Why does a particular CMS use iframes" and "is it wise to do so" are not suitable to this site's Q&A format. There will not be a singular correct answer, only a lot of arguments pro and con.

Comment: Okay. By the way, thank you Mr. Lister for your help.